# How can I integrate otp verification in my android app with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, one-time-password

I have implemented gmail sign in and email/password login method in my android app, the gmail sign in works successfully but while testing for email/password login/signup method I have tried to signup with wrong domain like "abc@gmal.com" it creates the account with wrong typed credentials also.
So I just wanted to integrate a sms otp verification method for verification while signup. How can I do this kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

With the new firebase Auth you can use 'Sign up confirmation'.

in firebase console -> Auth -> Email templates.

there is a way to make it without firebase auth, but it can save you some time.